# Light reflection and refraction confusion

Tags: reflection, refraction

I have a rectangular glass tank at my home(suppose ABCD).When there is no water,I can see through any face to it's opposite face as well as adjacent face.But after I add water to the tank and try to see,I can only see through the opposite face but adjacent face act as mirror and start reflecting everything.Why does this happen?Please help

Comment: try this experiment https://www.exploratorium.edu/snacks/critical-angle

Comment: Is the Refractive Index of aquarium glass not taken into account?

Comment: i think one can figure this out by considering what is called the critical angle. i think u need to take into account the air/glass and water/glass interfaces.